# How to Tweet using Oauth in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, tweets

I want to  develop a feature in my project where  I should be  able to tweet to twitter using oauth.
I had tried using direct  tweeting method as follows:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + text + "&url=" + encodeURIComponent("myurl");
```

but this requires login on each tweet.

Can anyone help me out………….